# Link malfunctions in css transition slider

Tags: css, slider

I pieced together two tutorials to create a CSS slider. Each slide is a list item with a background image, some text, and a link. The problem is all five slides link to the link of the last slide. Please help!

```
            <ul class="slideshow">
            <li><div class="slider-cta"><a href="what-we-buy.php"><h3>What We Buy</h3><p>From IT Networking to Test Equipment to medical equipment. We buy broad range of tech equipment.</p><p class="slider-button">See the full list here</p></a></div></li>
            <li><div class="slider-cta"><a href="sell-to-us.php"><h3>Sell Us Your Equipment</h3><p>We buy a full range of tech equipment and we buy from Fortune 500 companies to small businesses.</p><p class="slider-button">Get a quote in 24 hours!</p></a></div></li>
            <li><div class="container"><div class="slider-cta"><a href="who-we-buy-from.php"><h3>Who We Buy From</h3><p>Whether you are a international corporation or small business, liquidating old tech equipment gives you capital to invest in your future.</p><p class="slider-button">Learn more here</p></a></div></div></li>
            <li><div class="container"><div class="slider-cta"><a href="data-destruction.php"><h3>Data Destruction</h3><p>We take the security of sensitive information very seriously. Tech Buyer is trusted by many organizations with their data.</p><p class="slider-button">Learn more here</p></a></div></div></li>
            <li><div class="container"><div class="slider-cta"><a href="community.php"><h3>Community</h3><p>We partner with and support non-profits to give back to our the community.</p><p class="slider-button"> See more here</p></a></div></div></li>
        </ul>
```

(I stripped a lot of aesthetic and other code because it is not causing the issue)

```
.slideshow li,
.slideshow {
position: absolute;
top: 0;
left: 0;
height: 30%;
width: 100%;
}

.slideshow {
overflow: hidden;
list-style: none;
color: white;
}
.slideshow li {
background-size: cover;
background-position: center;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
opacity: 0;
filter: alpha(opacity=0);
-webkit-animation: images 6s linear 0s infinite;
        animation: images 6s linear 0s infinite;
overflow: hidden;
z-index: 0;
}

.slideshow li:nth-child(1) {
background-image: url("../img/what.png");
}

.slideshow li:nth-child(2) {
background-image: url("../img/hand-shake.png");
background-position: bottom;
-webkit-animation-delay: 6s;
        animation-delay: 6s;
}
```

Any suggestions on altering this code so the links work right without having to completely rewrite code? I finished the whole project and now it has this bug.

Comment: I feel I could add a z-index somewhere, maybe to go along with the transitions. I'm not sure though..

Comment: I decided to ditch this code and go with a jquery slider (it's called unslider). Forced me to learn some jquery!